# How to set the "HD" icon in Programs and Features?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I know you can set "the small icon" with `ARPPRODUCTICON`, but how do I set the bigger one (in the details panel)?

Right now Windows takes the same icon as `ARPPRODUCTICON` and re-sizes it, but this looks really bad.

The Wix installer has 2 different icons too, so it must be possible:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmQ0k.png

**Edit**

With IlirB's answer I created an Icon pack (.icl) and used that in Wix. Now Programs and Features picks the correct sizes automatically. This site suggests the following sizes: 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 256x256 http://www.visualpharm.com/articles/icon_sizes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single .ico file can have multiple sizes/dimensions of an icon.

I use IcoFX Portable (Google for it), create a new .ico add the icon that is large enough (256x256) then I create smaller variants of from it e.g. 256x256 + 128x128 + 48x48 + 32x32 + 24x24 + 16x16.

This way the icon will scale where necessary and look good.

Comment: Thanks, will try it as soon as I get the new icons.